# Is it possible to extract folders from Outlook to place on my C: without losing the folder structure?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Basically I have a whole bunch of Outlook folder directories with specific emails and attachments in each of them that I want to preserve and place on my C:.

Is it possible to do this or will I need to go through each email individually and save it to whatever folder I want it to be saved in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Outlook Export Wizard (second one down).

http://www.outlookimport.com/